# NOT NULL constraint failed: shipping_ship.user_id Django

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

So I'm working on a shipping website with the django rest framework. The website brings two to four people together so they can easily ship their goods together at the same time. But I'm facing a major stumbling block on the views where user book a shipping the code is below.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
class Container(models.Model):
    container_type = models.Charfield(max_length = 30, blank=False, null = False)
    max_users = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places =2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Ship(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='cont', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='shipper', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = (
    ('France', 'France'),
    )
    from_location = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=location, blank=False, null=False)

    to_location = (
    ('Lagos', 'Lagos'),
    ('Abuja', 'Abuja'),
    ('Abeokuta', 'Abeokuta'),
    ('Osun', 'Osun'),
    )
    to_location = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=to_location, blank=False, null=False)
    date_leaving = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.user
```

then my serializer.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Container, Ship



class ContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
      model = Container
      fields = '__all__'

class MiniContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields =['container_type', 'price']

class ShipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Ship
       fields = '__all__'
       read_only_fields = ('user', 'price')


class MiniShipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ship
        fields = ['container', 'from_location', 'to_location']
```

and now my views.py file which I have issues with

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404 

from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, CreateAPIView, ListAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView, RetrieveAPIView

from .serializers import ContainerSerializer, MiniContainerSerializer, ShipSerializer, MiniShipSerializer

from rest_framework import permissions, status

from rest_framework.response import Response


from .models import Container, Ship

class ShipAPI(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ShipSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       user = self.request.user 
       queryset = Ship.objects.filter(user=user)
       return queryset

    def Book_shipping(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       user = request.user 
       container = get_object_or_404(Container, pk=request.data['container'])
       if container.users.count() >= container.max_users:
           return Response('container already full')# here i'm trying to set limits so the users joining each container won't surpass the max users.
       cont = container(users=user)
       cont.save()
       from_location = (request.data['from_location'])
       to_location = (request.data['to_location'])
       date_leaving = int(request.data['date_leaving'])
       price = container.price / container.max_users
       cart = Ship(container=container, user=user, from_location=from_location, to_location=to_location, date_leaving=date_leaving, price=price)
       cart.save()
       serializer = ShipSerializer(cart)
       data ={'message': 'shipping successfully created',
             'data':serializer.data}
       return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

and then after testing the endpoint it returns this error:
IntegrityError at /Shipping/Ship/
NOT NULL constraint failed: shipping_ship.user_id

I've tried debugging and looking at it over and over again can someone please help me? Thanks in advance. And yes I've tried deleting migrations and the database.

Answer (score 0):

As your `Container` model have a `ManyToMany` relationship with the `User` model.
So it may not work like `cont = container(users=user)`

---

For me it worked like this:

```
cont = container.users.add(user)
cont.save()
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Still returns the same error